# Inside an accelerating lift, a bolt falls from its ceilings. Find the speed of the bolt with which it hits the floor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> Inside a lift accelerating up at $2\;\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$, a loose bolt falls from its
>   ceilings. If height of lift is $2\;\mathrm{m}$, find the speed of bolt wrt lift with which
>   it hits the floor. Initial speed of lift is $5\;\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}$ in upward direction. Take g=$10\;\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$

My attempt : In reference frame of lift:

Initial velocity of bolt= $0\;\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}$

Displacement = $-2\;\mathrm{m}$

I am facing trouble finding the acceleration of bolt in the reference frame of the lift.

Here's what I understand :

> 1) The lift is moving with $12\;\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$ in the upward direction and with
>   $10\;\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$ in the downward direction (only then can the net
>   acceleration be $2\;\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$ in the upward direction.
>
> 2) An observer standing in the lift will also be moving with net
>   acceleration of $2\;\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$ in the upward direction. The
>   acceleration of stone wrt lift i.e. ***$a_\mathrm{sl}$=$a_\mathrm{s}$-$a_\mathrm{l}$***
>
> where $a_\mathrm{s}$ is the acceleration of stone wrt ground
>
> $a_\mathrm{b}$ is the acceleration  of bolt wrt ground.
>
> Therefore, $a_\mathrm{sl}$=$2-2=0$ since both stone and bolt are moving
>   upward with an acceleration of $2\;\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$ in the upward direction.

From this, acceleration of bolt wrt observer in the lift=0

But this clearly doesn't lead me to the answer $4\sqrt{3}\;\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}$.

Where am I wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about relative accelerations so first think about relative velocities and how you found them.

Velocity of bolt relative to ground is equal to velocity of bolt relative to lift plus velocity of lift relative to ground.

Now do the same thing for accelerations.

In the frame of a stationary or non-accelerating lift the acceleration of free fall (acceleration of bolt relative to lift) would be $10-0 =10\,\rm ms^{-2}$.

If the lift was in free fall then in the frame of the lift the acceleration of free fall (acceleration of bolt relative to lift) would be $10-10=0\,\rm ms^{-2}$.

So now decide what the acceleration of free fall in the frame of the lift is when the the upward acceleration of the lift relative to the ground is $2\,\rm ms^{-2}$.